# zoom css/javascript

Tags: javascript, zooming

I would like to know how zoom property can be controlled through javascript,
like div.style.top , how to specify for zoom ?

Comment: It doesn't exists it seems. Here's a table with (I think all) css properties to javascript. http://codepunk.hardwar.org.uk/css2js.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link , useful . unfortunately no zoom as u have mentioned!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Firefox & Chrome (Webkit) equivalents to the IE-specific `zoom` property are, respectively, [`-moz-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform) and [`-webkit-transform`](http://webkit.org/blog/130/css-transforms/).

A sample code would be:

```
.zoomed-element {
    zoom: 1.5;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

You'd have to be a bit more careful with Javascript (test for existence first), but here's how you'd manipulate them:

```
el.style.zoom = 1.5;
el.style.MozTransform = 'scale(1.5)';
el.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(1.5)';
```

Comment: el.style.zoom = 1.5;
Works cool, I was giving value in wrong way !, What are the acceptable numbers for zoom ?? Is it between 1 to 2 and if I mention 1.5 is it 150 % ?

Comment: I'm not sure if zoom levels are limited. And yes, 1.5 => 150%

Comment: 1 == 100%, you can go beyond 2.

Comment: I am using above suggestion,
now how to zoom back to original size ? lil confused here , documentation says have to use value less than 1 to zoom out , and how to scale back to original size ??

Comment: Update: **`zoom` is also a valid Chrome CSS property.**

Comment: [IE9 supports transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh393506): `-ms-transform: scale(1.5);`. It works better than `zoom`; when comparing the results between IE9 and Chrome - it's not the same. (IE and Chrome handled `<body>` margins different with `zoom`, so went with `-*-transform`. IE versions before 9 bring other problems, had to disable the zooming feature. [There are workarounds.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805870/css3-transformscale-in-ie))

Comment: **As of 2016, the first part of this answer is completely incorrect.** `zoom` and `transform: scale` are separate CSS properties and with _entirely_ different effects, including different x/y coordinates calculation when interacting with zoomed elements from Javascript, different drag-and-drop image snapshots, and different layout positioning. Zoom imitates [browser zooming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278783/what-does-zoom-do-in-css) on a certain element and affects layout, transform-scale applies a scaling _after_ the element has been rendered and positioned into the layout.

Answer (score 3):

It is a property of `style`, but it's not supported by all browsers.  It's a [non-standard Microsoft extension of CSS](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom#) that Internet Explorer implements.  It is accessed like this:

```
div.style.zoom
```

Comment: I mainly test in Safari , In safari if I give zoom value in css style, it works but not div.style.zoom=200% or 200+"%" or 200 or "200%".

Comment: zoom is a non-standard property, so the webkit engine doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try a lightweight jQuery plugin called [Zoomoz](http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/). It uses CSS3 transform properties (translate, rotate, scale). Check out the "Zooming the jQuery way section. Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element").zoomTarget();
});
```