# CSS3 transform:scale in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, scale

I would like to use the CSS3 property transform:scale.

```
div
{
     transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
}
```

Is there a way to imitate this in Internet Explorer 8 and lower?
May be something with `filter` or a Javascript solution?

I've searched the web without any result.

Thanks a lot, Vincent

Comment: when asking questions like this, please specify the version(s) of IE you're asking about, because it makes a very big difference to the answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

IE9 supports transform:

```
-ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
```

For other versions of IE, there's a complex syntax. Something like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',
    M11=1.5320888862379554, M12=-1.2855752193730787,
    M21=1.2855752193730796, M22=1.5320888862379558);
```

Look [here](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) for more info.

Comment: You can also try the [CSS3 Transform to Matrix converter](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/) for one off conversions to IE's format.

Comment: -ms-transform: scale(0.5); should be enough for IE9 for a constant zoom.

Answer (score 13):

No, IE8 and earlier do not support the standard `transform` style. IE9 does support it though.

There are solutions you could try using the `filter` style, but they will be messy.

But for the simple case that you're describing in the question (basically a simple scaling down), you could use the IE-proprietary `zoom` property.

Since it's non-standard, the most common use of `zoom` is with`zoom:1`, which is used to fix a number of IE's layout glitches (particlarly in IE6 and IE7). But it does also do actual zooming as well, and you can use `zoom:0.5` to achieve the effect you're looking for.

The good thing about using `zoom` is that it is works in IE like any other normal CSS property (the `filter` alternative has some serious rendering quirks that you need to know about).

The only down-side of using `zoom` is that you'd need to disable it in IE9 or later, otherwise it'll interract with your `transform` style and have some unwanted effects. I'm not one to generally support the use of CSS hacks, but you could use the `/9` hack ([documented here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)) to make it only affect IE8 and earlier, meaning you can specify both the `transform` and the `zoom` in the same stylesheet, like so:

```
div {
  transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
  zoom: 0.5\9;
}
```

Otherwise you'd need to use conditional comments to determine whether to use it.

Obviously if you want to do anything more complex than a simple proportional scale, then `zoom` won't be suitable, but for a simple case like the one in your question it will be perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting reply. Unfortunatly zoom seems to scale only the text. And not the dimensions of my div.

Comment: yes, I guess it depends on what you actually need to achieve as to whether `zoom` will be suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the /9 hack tip. I was having some weird behavior in IE9 and 10 because I had zoom in the same style to cover IE8.

Comment: +1. Hope this doesnt interfere with chrome or firefox on specifying the ie hack

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(v=vs.85).aspx

although, filters in IE isn't easy to use and they are not always combined with other css effects....

but IE 9 support scale
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://github.com/pbakaus/transformie