# Css Transform IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Hello is here a way how to make this work in IE ?? 
http://www.victorgallo.cz/Cube/index.html

I searching about IE transformation but it seems like its not supported.. is here any different way or something ? in other browsers:Firefox , Chrome , Opera it work.. I hate IE !

```
  #cubeSpinner .two {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
-o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(300px);
background-image: url(images/main.jpg);
```

Comment: Have a look here - may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805870/css3-transformscale-in-ie AND HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie

Comment: What IE version(s) are you testing?

Comment: IE 10 and 9 pls go to link in question, try it in IE ;-)

Answer (score 1):

CSS transforms are supported in IE9 (with `-ms-` prefix) and IE10 unprefixed. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: I written that Css without prefixes but still in ie it doesnt work :-( i will try -ms- prefix

Answer (score 0):

css3 is not supported throug ie except IE10.
You can try using jQuery.animate()
[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: IE9 has support for several CSS3 features, including transforms.