# Change whole content of div size relatively

Tags: javascript, html, css

there is an HTML code like bellow:

```
<div class="home">
    <img id="back" src="" />
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="data" class="data">
       a few data that will change for every page, in fact content of each link will comes here by ajax.
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything here has an absolute size by pixel in width and height, now I want to minimize the whole thing in this div by 90%, so none of their position wont be changed. 
In fact I prefer to put whole of the code into another div and make it a little smaller than its actual size.

How could it be possible? I prefer CSS but jquery is Ok too.

Comment: yes, jquery can be an option

Comment: When you say width and height, do you just mean the dimensions of the div, or do you mean you want to scale down everything inside of it as well?

Comment: everything inside of it. just like this: .home {
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
  -moz-transform: scale(.9);
  transform: scale(.9);
 } its great the only problem is the browsers that it cant support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSS3 approach:

```
.home {
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
  -moz-transform: scale(.9);
  transform: scale(.9);
 }
```

ETA: Be aware of the [browser support for the transform property](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Comment: He wants to reduce it by 90%. So, shouldn't you be doing `scale(.1)` instead of `scale(.9)`? Nice approach though. Probably the easiest.

Comment: wow thanks this will work great in Chrome and firefox, but it won't work in IE.  how could fix this to work in IE too.

Comment: it's not even work in IE 10, and for record scale(.9) is what I mean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805870/css3-transformscale-in-ie Shows you how to do it in IE

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i guess

```
<script>
function resize() {
   $("div#data").height(10*$("div#data").height()/100);
}
</script>
```

Comment: That won't change the size of the fonts inside of it, etc.

Comment: Well, since he only mentioned width and height, I thought he didnt mean font-sizes. Reducing font sizes by 90% would actually make things pretty much unreadable..

Comment: You're right, his question is a bit vague on the details. Maybe he means just width and height. He also hasn't answered back about whether we can use jQuery to solve the problem.

Comment: yeap, and I want to resize the whole data (everything in div by class home

Answer (score -1):

Try to this one

```
<script>
function hideMenus() {
   $(".menu").find("ul").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: He didn't say he wants to hide it. He said he wants to make it 90% of it's original size.

Comment: yeap crush, I guess he didn't get the question.