# Transform scale css not work in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have tired everything transform to IE Matrix but transform scale css not work in ie8.

**Code:**

```
.fture_box ul li.fture_img img{
width: 451px;
height: 284px;
display: block;
margin: 0 0px 0 11px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
transform:scale(1.2);
} 

.ie8 .fture_box ul li.fture_img img{
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.2, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.2, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
}
```

Please tell me what i should do to make it compatible in ie8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 transform:scale in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805870/css3-transformscale-in-ie)

Comment: [IE8 doesn't support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support CCS3 transforms. While adding an extra library might not be what you want, you could look into [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) It uses CSS3, when available and falls back to Javascript on older browsers, like IE8. jQuery is optional and not a dependency.

```
$.velocity({scale: 1.2});
```

Answer (score 0):

Css transform isn't supported on IE8.

http://caniuse.com provides up-to-date browser support tables for support of front-end web technologies on desktop and mobile web browsers.

CSS transform: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform