# Transforme scale for older browsers?

Tags: html, css

This doesn't work with older browsers like IE

```
transform : scale(1,1.3); -moz-transform: scale(1,1.3); -o-transform: scale(1,1.3); -webkit-transform: scale(1,1.3);
```

Any workaround to make it work with older versions ?

Comment: And just keep this in mind too https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't work with older browsers like IE

This is wrong. It depends on which version of IE you are suporting.

There is the `-ms-` prefix for IE9. IE 10+ can perfectly run css3 2D transform nativelly, using `transform` property.

```
//IE 9
-ms-transform: scale(1, 1.3);

//IE 10+
transform: scale(1, 1.3);
```

So you can make almost all 2D tranforms into IE9+. Info via [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

But, of course, if you need to suport lower versions, like IE8, you have some workarounds, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805991/5037293).