# IE11 translate scale blurry image

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, internet-explorer-11, css-transforms

I am trying to create an animation of a balloon flying. All is weel in all modern browsers except IE11.

I am using translateX and translateY without any problem but scale is causing the image to become blurry.

```css
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
 .balloon-outer,
 .balloon-inner,
 .balloon {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  will-change: transform;
  pointer-events: none;
 }
 .balloon-outer {overflow-y: hidden;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: travel-x;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  transform: translateX(-20%);
 }
 .balloon {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: travel-y;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  transform: translateY(90%);
 }
 .balloon-inner {background:url("https://www.inty.com/wp-content/uploads/balloon.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / auto 40%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  animation-name: scale;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform: scale(3);
 }
}

 @keyframes scale { 
  0% {transform: scale(3);}
  80% {transform: scale(0);}
  100% {transform: scale(0);}
 }
 @keyframes travel-x { 
  0% {transform: translateX(-10%);}
  80% {transform:translateX(-45%);}
  100% {transform:translateX(-45%);}
 }
 @keyframes travel-y { 
  0% {transform: translateY(120%);}
  80% {transform:translateY(-70%);}
  100% {transform:translateY(-70%);}
 }
```

```html
<div class="balloon-outer"><div class="balloon"><div class="balloon-inner"></div></div></div>
```

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/xdLGEO

I have tried this trick which I have seen in several places but it made no difference.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
-ms-transform: translateZ(0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: It appears to be transform scale that is causing the blur.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: have you tried using the cssSandpaper library, as listed on caniuse.com? The url of the js is https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/cssSandpaper You may also find this other resource helpful http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/ (also listed on caniuse)

Comment: Hi @RReveley can you see this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGzddY in IE to verify if the blur effect is gone? If yes, then I think the main issue with IE11 is that `transform3d` causes the gpu to handle acceleration, and IE11's hardware accelerated rendering produces blurry images. It's not a problem on Edge though. Was facing the same issue, but finding actual cause of the issue was hard. This is the closest I've come to rationalizing IE's behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all your `translateX` and `translateY` to `translate3d` like:

```
@keyframes travel-x { 
    0% {transform: translate3d(-10%,0,0);}
    80% {transform:translate3d(-45%,0,0);}
    100% {transform:translate3d(-45%,0,0);}
}
@keyframes travel-y { 
    0% {transform: translate3d(0,120%,0);}
    80% {transform:translate3d(0,-70%,0);}
    100% {transform:translate3d(0,-70%,0);}
}
```

do the same everywhere you have been using `translates` in your example. translate3d enables hardware acceleration which will help with animations.
you can see [this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/) for more info.

Comment: I have updated the Codepen with your suggestion but it made no difference unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: when you try your codepen on IE11 do you still see the image blurred? i see it just fine on IE 11.0.10586

Comment: Still blurred. IE 11.873.10586.0 It appears to be the scale trnsform causing the trouble.

Comment: Actually, translate3d (and any other hw-accelerated transforms) cause blurry text in IE. Only the 2d-transforms produce sharp renders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fallback to IE-11 with the vendor prefix "-ms-transform".

for example:

```
.balloon-outer {overflow-y: hidden;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        animation-name: travel-x;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        transform: translateX(-20%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-20%);
    }
```

See the answer here.

[CSS3 transform:scale in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805870/css3-transformscale-in-ie)

Comment: This made no difference. IE is performing the transforms it's just doing it in a blurry way.

Comment: Ok, I was reading that IE has its own scale transform algorithm, but you shold call it with the vendor prefix: `transform: -ms-scale(3);`. Did you tried this?

Comment: I was skeptical but I did try it :(

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna make some tests and let you know if it works.