# Is it possible to animate the zoom css property

Tags: jquery, css, animation, zooming

Is it possible to animate the zoom animation

I've tried this but it is just the same as using the css property to set it.

```
$(this).animate({
    zoom: 0.5
}, 500);
```

Height animations work etc

Comment: Im sure its do-able via creating your own animate function. But doesn't this property only work in IE? Just wanted to check you are aware of this.

Comment: just found this answer on zooming in other browsers, may come in use for your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026294/zoom-css-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
-moz-transform: scale(2); 
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
```

**, but currently you cannot animate them with basic jQuery.

However, you can use a jQuery plugin for that, like [jquery.transform.js.](https://github.com/lrbabe/jquery.transform.js)

Please note the IE9 also supports the transform property, I found some info about it in [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865167/css3-transform-rotate-in-ie9)**

Answer (score -4):

You can even do in this way with jQuery :

```
jQuery(this).hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({
                marginTop: '-10px', //Bring image to top a little bit
                marginLeft: '-10px',
                width: '30px', //Zoom by 30 px
                height: '30px' 
            }, 500); /* 500 is the speed of how fast/slow image animates */

        } , function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({
                width: '15px', //Bring image back to original size
                height: '15px'
            }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: zoom actually scales text images backgrounds etc