# What Does 'zoom' do in CSS?

Tags: css

I found that some jQuery Plugin, in their css rule uses 'zoom' descriptor, I even Look into w3c website and found that it is used to magnify but how can I actually implement it? Or I have to Define some viewport? And how do I define such viewport ? Or i am wrong about the whole stuff ?

is it possible to use it like

```
a {
    zoom:1;
}

a:hover {
   zoom:2;
}
```

Comment: zoom, as expected, does simply zoom: http://jsfiddle.net/W24de/ ;)

Comment: You should have copied the code actually used in the jQuery plugin into your question. Most likely, the reason for its use is to provide hasLayout as mentioned by Ilia Akhmadullin. Nobody should be using the `zoom` property to actually "zoom" due to the incomplete browser support.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Zoom is not included in the CSS specification, but it is supported in IE, Safari 4, Chrome (and you can get a somewhat similar effect in Firefox with `-moz-transform: scale(x)` since 3.5). See [here](http://www.fix-css.com/2011/05/css-zoom/).

So, all browsers

```
 zoom: 2;
 zoom: 200%;
```

will zoom your object in by 2, so it's like doubling the size. Which means if you have

```
a:hover {
   zoom: 2;
}
```

On hover, the `<a>` tag will zoom by 200%.

Like I say, in FireFox 3.5+ use `-moz-transform: scale(x)`, it does much the same thing.

Edit: In response to the comment from `thirtydot`, I will say that `scale()` is not a complete replacement. It does not expand in line like `zoom` does, rather it will expand out of the box and over content, not forcing other content out of the way. See this in action [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_scale). Furthermore, it seems that `zoom` is not supported in Opera.

[This](http://htmlcssjavascript.com/css/using-css-zoom-and-css-transforms-for-a-better-increase-text-size-button/) post gives a useful insight into ways to work around incompatibilities with `scale` and workarounds for it using jQuery.

Comment: `zoom` and `transform: scale()` have significant differences. The transform origin is easily fixed, but the fact that `transform` does not affect the flow of content and `zoom` does is not simple to fix. Also, `zoom` doesn't seem to be supported in Opera. You should really edit your answer, it's misleading at the moment.

Comment: @thirtydot - Amended my answer. Thanks.

Comment: It would be interesting to use z-index with zoom

Comment: Hi, I suggest you modify this answer a little more to clarify the following: a) The zoom property is not standardised, so ideally it should be avoided b) Properties with -moz- prefix (any prefix really, Firefox is just more principled about it) are also experimental and WILL be removed when there is a standardised way to do things. These days, using or recommending -moz-transform is not a good idea.

Comment: @hallvors The question wasn't should I use zoom, it was What does zoom do. Its also in the answer that there are incompatibilities, and gives the relevant supported information.

Comment: No problem, although I think it's important to note whether something is standard or not.

Answer (score 37):

Surprised that nobody mentioned that `zoom: 1;` is useful for IE6-7, to solve most IE-only bugs by triggering [hasLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

This property controls the magnification level for the current element. The rendering effect for the element is that of a “zoom” function on a camera. Even though this property is not inherited, it still affects the rendering of child elements.

Example

```
 div { zoom: 200% }
 <div style=”zoom: 200%”>This is x2 text </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS `zoom` property is widely supported now > 86% of total browser population.

See: http://caniuse.com/#search=zoom

```js
document.querySelector('#sel-jsz').style.zoom = 4;
```

```css
#sel-001 {
  zoom: 2.5;
}
#sel-002 {
  zoom: 5;
}
#sel-003 {
  zoom: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sel-000">IMG - Default</div>

<div id="sel-001">IMG - 1X</div>

<div id="sel-002">IMG - 5X</div>

<div id="sel-003">IMG - 3X</div>


<div id="sel-jsz">JS Zoom - 4x</div>
```

[image: Browser Support: caniuse]

Answer (score 2):

Only IE and WebKit support zoom, and yes, in theory it does exactly what you're saying.

Try it out on an image to see it's full effect :)

Comment: False. Zoom is supported in IE, Opera, Safari 4, Chrome and Firefox with `-moz-transform: scale(x)` since 3.5.

Comment: Ah; Last time I tried it it didn't have any effect. CSS3 transforms aren't really the same, so no, Firefox doesn't support it. Perhaps internally 'zoom' is represented by a transformation since CSS3 in other browsers.

Comment: Actually, zoom doesn't seem to work in Opera either from a quick test. So what you're saying is that it works in IE and WebKit.

Answer (score 2):

zoom is a css3 spec for the @viewport descriptor, as described here

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#zoom-desc

used to zoom the entire viewport ('screen'). 
it also happens to zoom individuals elements in a lot of browsers, but not all. 
css3 specifies transform:scale should be used to achieve such an effect:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-functions

but it works a little different than the 'element zoom' in those browsers that support it.

Comment: It's very clear from the question that that's not the `zoom` that you're talking about.

Comment: yes :-) but strictly speaking, if the question is 'what does zoom do in css' this is the answer according to the css specifications. this is the only official zoom there is afaik, hence all the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

As Joshua M pointed out, the zoom function isn't supported only in Firefox, but you can simply fix this as shown:

```
div.zoom {
  zoom: 2; /* all browsers */
 -moz-transform: scale(2);  /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Those are two entirely different properties, though they yield similar results. Your example would zoom it out to 25% rather than 50%.