# Scale the contents of a div by a percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale

Building a CMS of sorts where the user can move around boxes to build a page layout (basic idea anyway).

I'd like to pull the actual contents in from the database and build out the "page", but have it display at 50% scale.

I realize I could have 2 sets of CSS - one for the actual front-facing page, and one for the admin tool and just shrink everything accordingly, but that seems like a pain to maintain.

I was hoping there might be some kind of jquery or CSS or something that would allow me to populate a div and give it the properties (?) of 50% scale.

Comment: possible duplicate of [complete styles for cross browser CSS zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393588/complete-styles-for-cross-browser-css-zoom)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can simply use the [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10278783/1348195) property:

```
#myContainer{
    zoom: 0.5;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Where myContainer contains all the elements you're editing. This is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if `zoom` is supported in all major browsers, why is `-moz-transform: scale(0.5);` required?  Or, are both statements required to cover all browsers?

Comment: @rinogo According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom) no current version of Firefox supports `zoom`, so I assume that's why `-moz-transform` is included.

Comment: `zoom` and `scale` are handled somewhat differently on some browsers, which means there's going to be a slight difference in the expected result.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488960/zoom-vs-scale-in-css3

Comment: If it's not looking good on firefox (i.e. not aligned properly) add this property `transform-origin: 0 0` or `-moz-transform-origin: 0 0` to fix it!

Comment: Even `transform-origin` is not enough. You can't really replicate the behavior of `zoom` with css transform.

Comment: Yes, it does. Just checked @AndroidDev

Comment: I wish I could give this answer more than one upvote! This is great!

Answer (score 33):

This cross-browser lib seems safer - just zoom and moz-transform won't cover as many browsers as jquery.transform2d's scale().

http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/

For example

```
$('#div').css({ transform: 'scale(.5)' });
```

## Update

OK - I see people are voting this down without an explanation. The other answer here won't work in old Safari (people running Tiger), and it won't work consistently in some older browsers - that is, it does scale things but it does so in a way that's either very pixellated or shifts the position of the element in a way that doesn't match other browsers.

http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/zoom

Or just look at this question, which this one is likely just a dupe of:

[complete styles for cross browser CSS zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393588/complete-styles-for-cross-browser-css-zoom)

Comment: transform and scale is the modern approach :)

Comment: But it doesn't resize the width/height compared to zoom, they work differently