# Scale whole page on lower resolution using jquery

Tags: jquery, scale

Is it possible to make a page for 1200px width with all measurements fixed as pixels and then adding code to scale everything down if the users width is too little?

I'm not asking for fluid CSS as I already made a fix-width page. I can't change all the measurements, but still need to find a way to scale the content down for smaller monitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can press ctrl++ you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to swap styles.

Comment: I don't want to change style, only to scale...when I using css transform to scale everything is moved...

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333254/scale-the-contents-of-a-div-by-a-percentage

Comment: I try that already, problem is that whole body moves min 300px from top of the screen...I need something that can scale whole page but not to disturb the positions...