# Zoom out shiny app at default in browser

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

When I open my shiny apps I find them look better when I zoom out to 75%. How can I force the shiny app to open at 75%, also on a server? I already tried what they mention in [this link](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/541) but it doesn't seem to work.
css:

```
.content-wrapper,
.right-side {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#controls {
  zoom: 0.75;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668647/4564432

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   tags$style("
              body {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
              "),
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This just shrinks the body to 80% but the content doesnt scale to the whole page. Any other solutions?