# How to zoom out page using RSelenium library in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to write a web-scraper using RSelenium Library in R. The last step of my work includes taking screenshot of a table on web page. To fit the whole table into the window I should zoom out the web browser (in that case it's firefox). I tried to use:

```
webElem <- remDR$findElement("css", "body")
webElem$clickElement()
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "control", "-"))
```

however it doesn't work. 
I saw also this thread: [Zoom out shiny app at default in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172024/zoom-out-shiny-app-at-default-in-browser) and found there promising fragment of code:
    library(shiny)

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   tags$style("
          body {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
              "),
```

I have no idea if it's possible to do something similiar in R Selenium and how to implement css scale modification in RSelenium. Iwould appreciate hints from someone more experienced with R.

Comment: Give [`splashr`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/splashr/index.html) a go for this. It's especially gd at full page screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out, that good solution to my problem was simple change of resolution in RSelenium:

```
remDR$setWindowSize(2496, 1404)
```

It works fine for my current purpose.