# ShinyDashboard - Zoom with CSS

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to implement zoom on my shiny dashboard as the layout looks better when it is at 80% zoom for the web browser.

I found an article on SO, however, it doesn't work for `Shinydashboard`. When I implement the `CSS`, I get a lot of dead white space.

Article to SO:
[Zoom out shiny app at default in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172024/zoom-out-shiny-app-at-default-in-browser)

Simple Code Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style("
              body {
             -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
             zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
             zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
             }
             "),
  "test")

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Picture showing problem (using chrome):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work if you modify your ui code some. It works for me when I do it this way:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
  tags$style("
              body {
             -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
             zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
             zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
             }
             ")
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, it is still showing the same look. A section is a white dead space :/ . I have tried it both on IE and Chrome. IE causes a white space on both right side and bottom whereas Chrome cause white space only on the bottom (refer to picture above)

Comment: That's strange. It works perfectly on my machine. Can you update the post with more of your code? Maybe there is something overriding the css?

Comment: That simplified version of the code is giving me the same issues. It is strange, I agree. I was thinking of a workaround of figuring out the viewpoint height and width dynamically and somehow using that to change the width and height but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Also @Alex, your code is missing commas between `dashboardHeader()` and `dashboardSidebar()` which will cause an error in your code. It only works because it is using memory cache for your latest working code, not actually zooming properly.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't actually use the code above to test my answer. I instead plugged the CSS into a couple of my "stable" ShinyDashboards in production to see if it worked. But I am confused now... it worked on two of my dashboards before I answered this question (not because of any memory cache though - I made sure to check this beforehand). But now I re-tested it after your latest comment and I am somehow having the same issue you are having. I am considering removing my answer because this behavior is strange. Also, I am using Firefox.