# Text a lot bigger in browser than app mode

Tags: shinydashboard

When I launch my shiny app in browsers mode, the font is a lot bigger than when I launch it in app mode. The font in the sidebar is too big, looks like 14 or 16px.

I have to zoom browser at 80% to get the same font size as when I launch in app mode.

How can I reduce the font size of my app when it's in browser, or in shinyapps?

Comment: Can you show some of the code? Otherwise how could we guess? If your font size is defined using some proportional method like `em`, maybe it's resizing with the window.

Comment: the css is all in AdminLTE.css. I have a custom.css but it's to resize the InfoBox from Shiny. I don't have any other css styling.

Comment: this worked for me  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918166/shinydashboard-zoom-entire-browser-with-css)