# Zoom out whole WordPress site

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, zooming

For zooming out on my WordPress I've used the following:

```
html { -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); zoom: 0.8; zoom: 80%; }
```

The code do not work on `Fireforx, Microsoft Edge` . Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Your question is unclear do you want zoom out your website screen ?

Comment: for more information check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668635/zoom-out-whole-website-using-jquery-or-css

Comment: No. Can you please check www.nacila.dk on chrome and then firefox.

Comment: i still need help :) +

Comment: I checked your code: the issue is with Mozilla hack. It scaled(compress) your website from top 20% and left 20%. That's why it's showing empty space on top. Please try different method to zoom out the website and you can also try decrease the wrapper size and instead of zoom out hole website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is updated CSS code: Just need to add **transform-origin: 50% 0;**
into your CSS code: But in Mozilla browser your website will view 80% only.

```
   html { 
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); 
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
        zoom: 0.8; 
        zoom: 80%; 
    }
```