# How to resize Google RECAPTCHA

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms, recaptcha

How can I resize the recaptcha container, I mean I want to keep everything in scale, just want the whole container is smaller to fit mobile view.

The original size right now:

[image]

And on mobile view it is not looking good:

[image]

Dont want to use any kind of customized theme or something, just want the whole container is smaller, say 70%, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Just saying there is a newer form of recaptcha from google you may want to look at also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try the css `zoom` property?

```
zoom:.7;
```

It's not supported everywhere, but if you're using responsive design such that it only happens on smaller screens (mobile browsers), those devices will generally know what to do with this.

Comment: You have any sample or link about using this zoom property? I need to apply it to my current style but I really not knowing much about css, just some basic stuff but I can follow if the instruction was not too crazy hard.

Comment: Umm... just add `zoom:.7;` to the current style? Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278783/what-does-zoom-do-in-css

Answer (score 3):

With reCAPTCHA version 2.0, there are new rules for the display of the widget and Google added tag attributes that change the way it is rendered.

The tag data-size can take the values of "normal", which is the default, and "compact", which fits in mobile device screens.

[image: new compact reCAPTCHA v2.0]

It is not the best looking widget, but it fits with less work than the other solutions.

For more attributes, check [Google's reCAPTCHA v2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Comment: Just to add a detail: The "data-size" attribute is attached to the <div> element that the recaptcha is created in. For example, ```<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-size="compact"></div>```