# how to reduce the size of the web page on browser to 90% by default?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I want that when my project of gwt loads on any browser its size on browser by default reduces to 90%.
I searched for it in javascript but couldnt find anything.

Comment: This may be an option http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/

Comment: Is there any script which changes the size to 90% on the browser and every things set accordingly as we do manually by using ctrl+(-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  int totalWidth = Window.getClientWidth();
  GQuery.$(RootPanel.get()).width((int) (totalWidth * 0.9));
}
```

For downloading GQuery, go to:

https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Downloads

and download the latest version (right now is gwtquery-1.4.2). Then, in your Xxx.gwt.xml introduce:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.query.Query'/>
```

And... happy coding!

Comment: i haven't used gQuery in gwt.is there something i want to import some package ?

Comment: any other way. like i have a project initially it got a form with some text boxes, the form i made using jsni. i tried using css its and also used this $doc.body.style.zoom="70%"; in jsni its working fine but for onlu that particular form . is there any way that whole project zoom level reduced to 90%

Answer (score 1):

Try with simple CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
     .zoom {
          zoom: 0.9; /* all browsers */
         -moz-transform: scale(0.9); /* Firefox */
      }
</style>
```

hosted JSP/HTML

```
<body class="zoom">
```

For more info have a look at [What Does 'zoom' do in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278783/what-does-zoom-do-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

add css on body of your html page of  gwt project directly and it will work perfectly for all page of your project.