# Setting style in JQuery using JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't get this following code sample working

```
var iZoomValue = Math.round(window.innerWidth/12.5);

$('body').css("zoom",iZoomValue);
```

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong over here ?

More inormation about [CSS Zoom](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/)

Comment: What are you trying? Do you know what `zoom` css property do?

Comment: @antyrat. I don't... What does it do? Is it a real property?

Comment: Are you testing in a browser which supports `zoom`? (if there exists any).

Comment: @antyrat of course, it zooms the element. If I use hardcoded like this `$('body').css("zoom","82");` it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Sachyn Look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026294/zoom-css-javascript

Comment: And does it work with hardcoded `$('body').css("zoom", 82);`?

Comment: I am testing in Chrome, it works fine when I use a hardcoded value

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: zoom is an IE only css property. are you testing the site in a fferent browser? try using a cross browser compatible property.
What is it your trying to do?
(good point Felix)

Comment: @DAVIEAC If its IE only property then why does it works in Chrome when I try to use `$('body').css("zoom", 82);` ?

Comment: Yes your correct Sachyn. I got saw the facts for my comment on a SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026294/zoom-css-javascript maybe the other vendors started to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your code is being fired when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // code here
});
```

Remember that `zoom` is a fairly new feature in the CSS3 spec and isn't supported by all browsers at this time.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fMZ6C/1/) (works for me in Chrome)

Comment: Or even shorter: `$(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that doing it in jQuery document.ready will solve it, as the OP has said that it works if he uses a hard coded value:

```
$('body').css("zoom","82");
```

My get feel is that either iZoomValue is not being set to what you think it is - perhaps an alert or console.log will help assert this?

Or that the jQuery css method accepts string parameter values (as in your hard coded example). iZoomValue will be a number, so the result will be

```
$('body').css("zoom",82);
```

It might be worth using a hard coded example with an integer as the param to assert this.

Hope this helps