# browser window width resizing with jquery

Tags: jquery, screen-resolution

browser window width resizing with jquery.

my website have container of 1080px width that contains content for website.

but when site is accessed through screen with less window with than 1080, the horizontal scroll comes in screen and content are not perfectly viewable, to view full content user need to scroll horizontally.

this scroll is removed by zooming in browser window.
so I want that when user with low resolution screen visits the site jquery zoom their screen size automatically.

jquery checks resolution or width of window and if resolution is less than 1100px then jquery zooms window. (that we manually do by pressing ).

please help me.
Thank You

Comment: take a look at responsive design. Here are some [tutorials](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/). You can also get screen size, calculate zoom factor and apply [zoom css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026294/zoom-css-javascript) . (That's litterly what you're asking). But I prefer Klaus' solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add this `meta` tag to your html's `head`. It should give you the effect you want for mobile devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```